# C++ Parse library for Qt applications

Tags: c++, qt, parse-platform

I'm aware there is no official C++ library for Parse (https://parse.com). I've got a desktop variant of an app written using Qt C++ for OSX/Windows that needs to talk to Parse. I'm embarking on writing my own client for the Parse REST API based on the PHP library (https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library) and the Qt network classes. Would you recommend a different approach?

The data I am saving is pretty basic, some objects and some geo data, but it would be nice to have a general solution to share with others. I will happily release whatever I come up with via GitHub, and all the better if this can lead to a group of us sharing the load.

Cheers!

Comment: If Parse expose a REST API you only need to build an url properly and then make the request. You can read [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?][1]

  [1]:http://How%20do%20you%20make%20a%20HTTP%20request%20with%20C++?

Comment: [parseqt](https://github.com/frameworklabs/parseqt) may be a good start.

Comment: right, I looked at parseqt. It is BlackBerry-specific, but it will be useful to look at.